# DateTime field display diffrent values when editing and when viewing

Tags: document-library, content-type, date-time, site-column, word

We have an Office 365 2013 Business Premium subscription and are using Sharepoint online as our Intranet solution.

Our problem seems related to [DateTimeField and timezone conversion problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/datetimefield-and-timezone-conversion-problem)

**The scenario is as follows:**
-Set Site Time Zone to UTC + 2
-Create Site Column "Mötestid" as a Date Field
-Create Site Content Type "Kallelse"
-Add Site Column "Mötestid" to content type "Kallelse"Create a word template for content type "Kallelse"
-Add QuickPart "Mötestid" to the a Word template
-Add column "Mötestid" to a library view
-Create a new document using the created Word template.
-Set document property "Mötestid" to 2015-08-10 18:30
-Save document

**The problem is:**
-Library view and SP document propery correctly shows time in "Mötestid" as 18:30
-SP document view incorrectly shows time in "Mötestid" as 20:30
-When editing the document, time in "Mötestid" is rendered correctly as 18:30

Any help is appreciated

**Screenshots**
[image]